# pwdField.setEchoChar(char(0)); does not compile on Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

This is the swing statement for the password field:

```
private javax.swing.JPasswordField passwordField;
```

I was building a listener for a checkbox which displays or not the password:

```
/*Shows or not the password*/
private void showCheckboxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        if(showCheckbox.isSelected()){
            //shows the passwork
            passwordField.setEchoChar(char(0));
        }
        //else...passwordField.setEchochar('*');

    }
```

But this does not compile, as if the problem is with
`char(0)`:

> error: '.class' expected
>
> passwordField.setEchoChar(char(0));
>
> 1 error
>
> BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

But this sounds to me weird because I used the same code on another IDE, Intellij, and it worked without problems...

Comment: `char` is a keyword in Java. `char(0)` isn’t a legal method call. Did you change variable names between the IDEs? Or the location of the brackets?

Comment: Nope. And that's the video I referred to [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bApp35dCgB0)

Comment: Yep, and that video shows the location of the brackets changed, as per my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a cast like this:

`passwordField.setEchoChar((char) 0)`

Comment: Thanks. **Solved**

Comment: @Teorema Instead of commenting, please accept the answer by clicking on the tick. Cheers.